# Для чего ввели U+1160?

Tags: unicode

В unicode есть симол который похож на пробел, но это не пробел. Его код — `U+1160`. Выглядит он так вот так: 'ᅠ' (без кавычек). Так какую функцию выполняет этот символ в unicode, для чего он создан?

Comment: Это символ-заполнитель для корейского языка. *Могу предположить*, что он резервирует место в многоэтажных корейских иероглифах в случае, когда требуется их неполный вариант.

Comment: Подробнее о сборке корейских иероглифов можно почитать [у Microsoft-а](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otfntdev/hangulot/features.aspx). Там же, кстати, дана ещё и [вводная](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/OpenTypeDev/hangul/intro.htm) по письменности хангыль.

Comment: @Arhad Кстати о птичках, в Корее пишут не иероглифами :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну тогда пусть будет просто глифами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hangul Jungseong Filler* или `U+1160` используется для сборки корейских иероглифов. В html можно вызвать как `&#x1160;`

Comment: А можно пример?